# In Jupyter notebook, using Python 2.7, why do I get an error when importing data and web from pandas_datareader?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data, web
```

I then get this error:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c2f88f94fe78> in <module>()
      2 import datetime
      3 import pandas as pd
----> 4 from pandas_datareader import data, web
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name web
```

I already used pip install and conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda pandas-datareader but it still didn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: how are you launching the notebook? are you sure jupyter notebook is installed for the same "python" which has `pandas_datareader` installed?

Comment: It's not web but wb. Try:
`from pandas_datareader import data, wb`

Comment: @jasonm I'm using Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda2) Application. How do I check that? I'm sorry as I'm just learning python.

Comment: @Arn I will try will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Arn using wb, it has passed that line but I'm having an error. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_data_yahoo' which I think I should research more or ask in a different question if my research fails.